# LINQ Query OrderByDescending not recognizing lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm fairly new to LINQ, but I think I'm getting the hang of it.

I'm trying to group a select statement, then order it descending. I've got pretty far just looking through other questions, but when I try to attach the `OrderByDescending()` function, lambda expressions I try to add are not recognized by intellisense.

```
var test = db.UserPokemons.Where(x => x.PkmnDataId == pokemon.Id && x.StepsToHatch == 0)
                          .GroupBy(n => n.User1.Country).OrderByDescending();
```

So, for example, `.OrderbyDescending(x => x.User1.Country)` does not contain a definition for `User1`.

Is this to do with the ordering of my statements? I think it's because I'm calling `GroupBy` before `OrderBy`, but I can't wrap my head around how to fix it.

How can I order my groups?

Oh! Nearly forgot - I only want the top 3 countries, so is there an easy way to restrict that as well?

- How to use `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending` in the same LINQ function
- How to select only the top/first 3 groups

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to order the groups, or order the items within the group?

Comment: I would like to order the groups

Comment: if you want to order by country then use  .OrderbyDescending(x => x.Key).Take(3)

Comment: `x.Key` is what I needed - I wasn't sure how it took the x values when x was sorted into groups. It works perfect now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var countriesInOrder = db.UserPokemons.Where(x => x.PkmnDataId == pokemon.Id && x.StepsToHatch == 0).
                GroupBy(n => n.User1.Country).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).Take(3).ToArray();
```

Got it - the lambda expression needs to go to the `x.Key` after grouping.
(Thanks jitender!)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
 var test = db.UserPokemons.Where(x => x.PkmnDataId == pokemon.Id && x.StepsToHatch == 0).
        GroupBy(n => n.User1.Country).Select(x=>x.First()).OrderByDescending().Take(3);
```

Comment: That didn't quite work - `OrderByDescending()` needs parameters and the `First()` throws errors too. I've got it to work though - thank you for the help!